# How to simulate a very slow android phone?

Tags: android, performance, android-emulator, genymotion

I've a Moto X with Android 4.4.4 and I also use Genymotion Emulators to develop apps. My question is -- how can i simulate my app performance/behavior for very slow/old phones and also phones with less memory.

Comment: create a emulator with low heap and ram size.

Answer (score 1):

To simulate less memory, simply use less memory. Below is a demonstration for how to do this using GenyMotion. Click settings (*the wrench icon*) next to the virtual device to go to configuration then lower the `Base Memory`.

**FROM**

[image]

**TO**

[image]

Afterward, you should be able to simulate the performance of your app on a slower device. If you need to raise or lower your memory usage move the `Base Memory` value up or down by 1024.

This can also be done directly in the VirtualBox Settings with slightly more configuration options.